# Position a <div> over another <div>

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DataViewer" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>

<div style='border: 0px; width:600px;overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;'>
    <div style='float:left;'><%# Eval("DriverId") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div style='border: 3px solid black; float:left; height: 50px;'>
        <div style='border: 0px; float:left; height: 50px; width:<%# Eval("OrderCount") %>cm;'><%# Eval("OrderCount") %></div>
        <div style='position:relative; border: 0px; float:right; height: 50px; width:<%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %>cm; background-color: red;'><%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %></div>
    </div>
</div>
<BR/>

</ItemTemplate>
```

instead of placing the divs one besdies another, i need to put them on over another: image attached
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/CwfpG/)

```
<div style='border: 0px; width:600px;overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;'>
    <div style='float:left;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div style='border: 3px solid black; float:left; height: 50px;'>
        <div style='border: 0px; float:left; height: 50px; width:150px'>
            <div style='float: right; border: 0px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: red;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```